# Check if filename exists and

Tags: php

I wondered if there were a way to check if the filename exists and then to add a number after it, I know this - in a basic for is possible so if someone does it once it'll add `1` after it.

But how would you get it to check if someone has done it more than once? So the first time it would add a `1` then a `2` then a `3` and so on?

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$compile = $title. "\r\n" .$content;
$content = $compile;
$path = "../data/" .md5($title). ".txt";
$fp = fopen($path,"wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);

$con=new mysqli("###","###_public","###","###"); 
if (!($stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `blog_posts` (`post_title`,`post_content`,`post_date`) VALUES (?,?,?)")) || !is_object($stmt)) {
    die( "Error preparing: (" .$con->errno . ") " . $con->error);
}
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['title'], $path, $_POST['date']);
if($stmt->execute()) { 
    echo "Successfully Posted";
} else {
    echo "Unsuccessfully Posted";
}
    $stmt->close();
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: PHP has a built-in function check if a file exists - [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/file_exists)

Comment: Why not wait till after you have ran your `insert` then simply use the unique id for `blog_posts` as the filename, that way you know it is unique and easy to retrieve the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea would be like this:

```
$basefilename = "somefile";
$filename = $basefilename;
$i = 0;
while(file_exists("../data/".$filename.".txt") $filename = $basefilename.(++$i);
```

Adapt as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
<?php
if(file_exists($filename)) { // check if the file exists in the first place
   $i = 1;
   while(file_exists($filename.$i)) { // check if the filename with the index exists. If so, increase the $i by 1 and try again
      $i++;
   }
   rename($filename, $filename.$i); // rename the actual file
} else {
   // file did not exist in the first place
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much how I used to do it, but it kinda violates DRY with the two `file_exists` calls ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not add strings at the end of file name - you would eventually
   hit the OS file name length limit pretty soon. You would also fail
   to recognize the last added number, when the string gets too big -
   you'd have to parse all the numbers from the beginning.
2. Use [glob()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to search for a file name.
3. Parse the file names found for the number at the end and increment
   that number.
4. Use [rename()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) on the file name and check the return status to
   avoid racing conditions.
5. Generally avoid that - use a database or any other system that
   supports atomic operations.